# How to specify a non-constant integer string-length?

Tags: c, string-formatting

I have an array of strings that I would like to print.  I know to print them you use `%s` and for instance `%.6s` to specify printing 6 elements of string.  Is there any way so that I can specify a non-fixed integer value of times to print? (For instance have it print `i` times in the below example).  Below is my loop as is currently done.

```
for (i=0;i<num_locations;i++){
    printf("%.6s",&locations[i][0]);        
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you really read the checklist before asking: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 2):

You can use `*` to pass a nonconstant argument: `printf("%.*s", width, str);`.